# How big would the lakes presented in the two pictures presented be in square mileage?

Tags: geography, water-bodies, maps

[image]

[image]

The reason I posted two separate maps instead of just one is that in the second picture, Megalakes Chad and Congo look much bigger than on the first one. How big would each and every one of those lakes be in square miles?

Comment: (1) Obtain a map outlining Africa in an equal-area projection. (For example, use the free G.Projector from NASA.) (2) Draw your lakes and fill them with a distinctive color. (3) Use your favorite raster image editor to count the pixels of that distinctive color. (4) Erase the lakes and fill Africe with a distinctive color. (5) Repeat step 3 to count the pixels in Africa. (6) Knowing that Africa has 30,370,000 km², compute the areas of the lakes.

Comment: Moved this from an answer to a comment: 

I found Lake Chad's Wikipedia page and it says the area is 590 sq miles, but trying to search for "Lake Congo" leads to a lake in Costa Rica instead of Africa. Moreover, the "Lake Congo" I saw is sizable, but tiny *compared to Chad* at 0.57sq miles (340 or so acres), so it's nowhere near as big as the lake on your map. Are the rest of these lakes real, or fictional?

Either way, you could eyeball the other lakes and figure they're less/more than Lake Chad's size as a basic scale.

Link to Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Chad

Answer (score 1):

**GIMP**

[image]

Download GIMP. It's free!

Use the Histogram tool under  Colours -> Info -> Histogram.

See that tiny **Count:** number in the bottom right. That's the number of pixels in the selected region.

You can use this to work out the area of the lakes. Just compare to the area of Africa. Look that up somewhere else.

For best results start with the equal area projection map of Africa.

[image]

I am told the Earth is a ball and not a map. The above map is special in that if you draw a region on the map then it has the same area as the corresponding region on the ball. Gosh, Africa is BIG.